# R chr data type to Date and Time with AM

Tags: r

In my table (over 12K lines), I have a Column named Sleep Day that comes in a chr type data with the following info template: 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM

I tried to convert the chr to Date and time type, but it only shows the Date...

Here is my function (table´s name: conjunta_n):

```
conjunta_n$SleepDay<-as.Date(conjunta_n$SleepDay, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

The problem is that I keep getting one of these two results:

Output 1:  2020-04-12

Output 2: NA

I haven't been able to get the time part, nor the AM on a date and time template.

The desired output is:

4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM (in date-time type)

Please help!

(I`m new in R)

Comment: use `as.POSIXct(conjunta_n$SleepDay, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` instead of `as.Date`

Comment: Note that you have Date and Time. `as.Date` is only used for `Date` and not with `Date and Time. Use `strptime` or `as.POSIXct` or `as.POXISlt` but use `format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"`. Note that you have `%y` instead of `%Y`. Also you are using 24hr clock system ie `%H` instead of 12hrs clock system ie `%I %p`. The `%p` is used to indicate which half of the day, ie AM or PM. run `help('strptime')` to check on all the formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lubridate` package:

```
lubridate::mdy_hms("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM")
lubridate::mdy_hms("4/12/2016 12:00:01 AM")
```

But there is a gotcha that is unrelated to your conversion method.  If the time is exactly midnight, then R will usually print just the date.  You can see this here:

```
> lubridate::mdy_hms("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM") %>% str
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-04-12"
> lubridate::mdy_hms("4/12/2016 12:00:01 AM") %>% str
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-04-12 00:00:01"
```

You can also use `dput` to check that the above two examples differ by one second, but are otherwise the same.